# Error in running mpi codes on mac os 10.9.3 mavericks

Tags: architecture, makefile, mpi, osx-mavericks, x86-64

Suddenly I cannot run any mpi program. I tried running a simple mpi example that I found online and used to work on my computer.

this is the example http://mpitutorial.com/mpi-hello-world/

the error I'm getting when I type `make` is the following

```
ld: can't write output file: mpi_hello_world for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [mpi_hello_world] Error 1
```

This is the make file content

```
EXECS=mpi_hello_world
MPICC?=mpicc

all: ${EXECS}

mpi_hello_world: mpi_hello_world.c
 ${MPICC} -o mpi_hello_world mpi_hello_world.c

clean:
    rm ${EXECS}
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong?

Comment: Without seeing how the makefile works, it's hard to help you.

Comment: Looks like a permission error! Are you sure about permissions on your current working dir?

Comment: How did you install MPI?